# What's the next image?

Tags: visual

Can someone help with guidance for the following puzzle?

[image: Image puzzle]

Thanks and regards,
Todor

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it is maybe

> A

since

> I can't find a correlation between the number of big white or small white squares in each picture. There are 3 black stars in each picture, but all the pictures have that, so that doesn't help us. However, each picture in the first row has an odd number of black diamonds, and A is the only option that continues that trend. I'm not sure if there is any other pattern that I'm missing.

By the way, where did you find the puzzle? I think the community on Puzzling usually tries give credit to the original author of the puzzle if it came from somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was from an IQ test that my friend took and these were the 2 questions that he couldn't answer. It was a local IQ test that they do in schools. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to the question.

> The star with 5 peaks have even number of squares.
> The star with 6 peaks have odd number of squares.
> Only A have this correlation.

Comment: haha for some reason I didn't see that some stars have 5 points and some have 6...